# Static Tab not appearing in Microsoft Teams App

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have sideloaded the app into the tenant through the Microsoft Teams Admin Centre. The app consists of:

- Compose Extension.
- Static Tabs.

So, the issue here is when the users log into the Microsoft Teams Apps on the mobile device, they can see the compose extension but not the Static Tabs.

**Note regarding the user:**

- New user was created.
- Never logged from the Teams desktop app.

**Question**: How the app installed (pinned) by the admin appear for all the users irrespective of what device they are logged in to?

Comment: Do you have both a `contentUrl` and a `websiteUrl` property set for your static tab in the app manifest?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, yes both are set to the same URL.

Comment: @GauravGupta - Could you please confirm if you tried adding the app using "Add app" in the mobile? We are trying to add using "Add app" and it does not show list of apps.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, I tried that as well but didn’t saw my app listed there.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, can you provide some guidance is it a bug on Teams side or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: We are checking this with the engineering team, we will update you once we get the information. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravGupta - Are you facing this issue in Android & iOS both ?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, yes on both

Comment: Thank you for confirming. We got the following response from engineering team - The sideloaded apps will always appear on mobile. There are no restrictions for sideloaded apps for static tabs. For config tabs, we just check the websiteUrl property in setSetting configuration. So, the engineering team is investigating further on this issue as this is not the expected behaviour. We will update you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, I am unable to see the StaticTabs on mobile devices until I login on Desktop (as mentioned in the question above) is that something your engineering team is looking into?

Comment: Yes, Team is looking into it. We will keep you posted if there are any updates.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT This issue is preventing our customers from going live with the service. Can we get an update on this? Also, this issue is not coming on Extension in some cases.

Comment: Hello Gaurav - We are able to repro the issue and informed engineering team. Engineering team has started further investigation on the issue but we don't have exact ETA to share with you.

Comment: @GauravGupta - Please help me with below questions.
Is it happening only with this account or other accounts as well ?
Is it also happening on other clients (web)?
Is this a regression? [ was working previously ?]

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft,  the issue is not consistent it happens for some accounts in some tenants. I tested with one user that the compose app is there on phones but for others, that's not the case. And Sidebar was never appeared in first instance after multiple login-logout it appeared, this technique also, worked in some cases

Comment: @GauravGupta - My queries was regarding this issue "unable to see the StaticTabs on mobile devices until I login on Desktop"
Are you not facing this issue now ?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, yes I am  - i just explained the full scenario again in my last comment

Comment: Hello @GauravGupta - I need below information to proceed further for investigation. 1) What is the Teams version?  2) When you Side loaded the app through Admin portal and never logged in to any of the clients, that means you never added the app to Personal scope at all, is that right? 3) Can you please follow the same steps as you have done till now and also add the app to personal scope(i.e Add the app) and see if you are still not able to see the app? 
4) Once you have tried these and still can't see the app, would it be possible to get logs from your device (if you are on prod build)

Comment: What do you mean by adding in `Personal scope`, as the app is added to the team and the users are part of that team, doesn’t that mean should be there for them

Comment: When you added an app in the team the app became available to the team(you and other members) and that's why you are able to see it in compose extension, but it has not been added to your personal usage and thus you can't see your side loaded app's static tab.

Comment: To make the app's static tab available for you, you need to add the app for your personal usage through one of below options
1. Click on Add for me option by going into Manage apps where your side loaded apps must be available 2. Click on 3 dots on left menu bar on web/desktop, find you app and click on Add for me, same thing you can also do on mobile, you can click on 3 dots on the bottom bar, click on Add app(it should be at the end of the grid), browse your app from the list shown and click on Add.

Comment: Post this, you should be able to see the app's static tab under App tray which opens by clicking on 3 dots in the bottom bar of Teams app.

Comment: so every user has to do that?

Comment: @GauravGupta - Yes.

Comment: @GauravGupta - Could you please share the above asked information. Thanks.

Comment: but if every user has to do the steps from their side that can be hard to manage in a large organisation to train people?

Comment: Hello @GauravGupta - This is by design behavior. Alternative way is to proactively install the bot for all the users in the tenant. Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet

Comment: @GauravGupta - For personal scope user has to install it, but for teams scope if you install it will be available for all the team members.

Comment: Could you please provide below information to proceed further for investigation. 1) What is the Teams version? 2) When you Side loaded the app through Admin portal and never logged in to any of the clients, that means you never added the app to Personal scope at all, is that right? 3) Can you please follow the same steps as you have done till now and also add the app to personal scope(i.e Add the app) and see if you are still not able to see the app? 4) Once you have tried these and still can't see the app, would it be possible to get logs from your device (if you are on prod build)